# How to animated the circle (like in the gif) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

[image: gif]

How can I make animated circle like this in Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options for you.

You can use [percent_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator) package.

You can use `CustomPainter` as [in this blog post](https://medium.com/@calebkiage/creating-an-animated-progress-indicator-in-flutter-part-1-c7a95453a883).

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [this pub](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator). Hope this helps. this holds exactly what you are looking for. with few tweaks you can have any type of child elements inside the indicator. Cheers!!